# Editing an svg file

Tags: svg

I have an svg file that maps out a theater seating area. Currently it draws each seat as a circle. I would like to change this to a square.

Here is the code I have

```
id="path7"
title="F46"
d="m 281.9461,86.766 c -2.796,0 -5.071,-2.275 -5.071,-5.071 0,-2.796 2.275,-5.072        5.071,-5.072 2.797,0 5.072,2.276 5.072,5.072 0,2.796 -2.275,5.071 -5.072,5.071 z"
inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
fill="#CDCDCD"
stroke="#CDCDCD"
stroke-width="3" />
```

If anyone could help on this it would be great

Comment: can you please supply codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: If your user agent is inkscape, you can edit `d=.......` in the output file. If your user agent is Raphel, D3.js or svgjs, then u update the function that creates this circle.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. use a library for SVG  http://www.svgjs.com/
2. manipulate Text by specifications.
    change `d=m 281.9461, 86.766 c <List of Coordinates>`
    to `d=m 281.9461, 86.766 c <top left coord>, <top right coord>, <bottom right coord>, <bottom left coord>`

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the code I have above with this

```
d="m 494.33766,216.207 h -12 v -12 h 12 z"
```

Some great information on the topic here which gave me the exact information I was looking for

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/flex/9781449388195/graphics/use_path_to_draw_a_shape_with_stroke